# How does Django's ORM manage to fetch Foreign objects when they are accessed

Tags: python, django, orm

Been trying to figure this out for a couple of hours now and have gotten nowhere.

```
class other(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)


others = other.objects.all()
o = others[0]
```

At this point the ORM has not asked for the o.user object, but if I do ANYTHING that touches that object, it loads it from the database.

```
type(o.user)
```

will cause a load from the database.

What I want to understand is HOW they do this magic.  What is the pythonic pixie dust that causes it to happen.  Yes, I have looked at the source, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Django uses a [metaclass](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) ([`django.db.models.base.ModelBase`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/base.py#L22)) to customize the creation of model classes.  For each object defined as a class attribute on the model (`user` is the one we care about here), Django first looks to see if it defines a `contribute_to_class` method.  If the method is defined, Django calls it, allowing the object to customize the model class as it's being created.  If the object doesn't define `contribute_to_class`, it is simply assigned to the class using `setattr`.

Since `ForeignKey` is a Django model field, it defines [`contribute_to_class`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L872).  When the `ModelBase` metaclass calls `ForeignKey.contribute_to_class`, the value assigned to `ModelClass.user` is an instance of [`django.db.models.fields.related.ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L266).

`ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor` is an object that implements Python's [descriptor protocol](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors) in order to customize what happens when an instance of the class is accessed as an attribute of another class.  In this case, the descriptor is used to [lazily load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) and return the related model instance from the database the first time it is accessed.

```
# make a user and an instance of our model
>>> user = User(username="example")
>>> my_instance = MyModel(user=user)

# user is a ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor
>>> MyModel.user
<django.db.models.fields.related.ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor object>

# user hasn't been loaded, yet
>>> my_instance._user_cache
AttributeError: 'MyModel' object has no attribute '_user_cache'

# ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor.__get__ loads the user
>>> my_instance.user
<User: example>

# now the user is cached and won't be looked up again
>>> my_instance._user_cache
<User: example>
```

The `ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor.__get__` method is called every time the `user` attribute is accessed on the model instance, but it's smart enough to only look up the related object once and then return a cached version on subsequent calls.

Comment: Is there any easy way to force the cache the related object? I gooogled django.db.models.fields.related.ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor and found this post...

Comment: Are you trying to pre-populate the cache? I think [`QuerySet.select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) and [`QuerySet.prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related) may be what you're looking for.

If you're trying to invalidate the cache, I think your best bet is just to delete the cache attribute on the model instance.

Answer (score 1):

This will not explain *how* exactly Django goes about it, but what you are seeing is Lazy Loading in action. Lazy Loading is a well known design pattern to *defer* the initialization of objects right up until the point they are needed. In your case until either of `o = others[0]` or `type(o.user)` is executed. This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) may give you some insights into the process.

Comment: Yea, I understand the why, I was looking for the explanation of how they pulled this off.

Answer (score 0):

Properties can be used to implement this behaviour. Basically, your class definition will generate a class similar to the following:

```
class other(models.Model):
    def _get_user(self):
        ## o.users being accessed
        return User.objects.get(other_id=self.id)

    def _set_user(self, v):
        ## ...

    user = property(_get_user, _set_user)
```

The query on User will not be performed until you access the .user of an 'other' instance.