# Constructucting filters for a class with two foreign keys to the same class in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filters

I have a Django model with two different foreign keys to the same model. I have defined unique related_names for each field.

The problem occurs when I try to filter the class according to these fields.

This is the model I am working on:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    f_key1 = models.ForeignKey(Bar, related_name='key_1')
    f_key2 = models.ForeignKey(Bar, related_name='key_2')
    someNumber = models.IntegerField()
```

This is how I construct the filters:

```
list = Foo.objects.filter(Q(f_key1=bar1) | Q(f_key2=bar1)).order_by('-someNumber')[:3]
```

And this is the error message I get:

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the value of bar1? Try something like this: list = Foo.objects.filter(Q(f_key1_id=bar1) | Q(f_key2_id=bar1)).order_by('-someNumber')[:3] if the bar1 is a integer

Comment: bar1 is an instance of Bar. I have a list of Bar objects and I iterate over them os follows:
for bar1 in listOfBarObjects:
    -- I do the filtering here --

Comment: Without looking at the actual code in the correct context, i cannot say what you are doing wrong here. But I think changing f_key1=bar1 to f_key1=bar1.pk should fix it. Reading this will probably give you a better answer to what is going wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597762/how-does-djangos-orm-manage-to-fetch-foreign-objects-when-they-are-accessed